# En el historial de las colas de revisión de Meta no es posible identificar qué publicaciones fueron borradas

Tags: bug, meta, colas-de-revisión, diseño

Estaba mirando mi historial de revisiones para la cola [*Votos de cierre* en el sitio principal](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/review/close) y me fijé que se ve así:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como resulta gráficamente claro, los títulos de las preguntas son clicables si no están eliminadas (yo tengo menos de 10 K de reputación, luego las preguntas borradas no las puedo ver).

Sin embargo en [el historial de meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/review/close) se ve así:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso no es posible identificar cuál es clicable y cuál no, por mucho que unas tengan enlace y otras no. Por tanto, tampoco es posible identificar de un solo vistazo qué preguntas están eliminadas.

Veo que se mencionó en SO: [It's hard to identify deleted questions from the review history on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289322/1983854)

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo contigo. Pero atendiendo a que la pregunta que enlazas en meta.so se hizo hace 4 años y no obtuvo mucha atención por lo que veo, no parece que sea una prioridad para el equipo de StackExchange...

Comment: @Pikoh cierto... supongo que a este ritmo antes llegaré a 10 K que ver esto resuelto sin esa reputación :)